# Django, python syntax error while running makemigrations (DecimalField choices)

Tags: python, django, django-models, allegro-pl

In my application, I'm calling API to create choices for DecimalField in models.py.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
import re
from suds.client import Client
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class Allegro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.webapi_key = 'hidden key'
        self.country = 1
        self.client = Client('https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php?wsdl')
        self.client.options.cache.setduration(hours=1)
        self.starting_time = '24h'

    def get_categories(self):
        category_list = self.client.service.doGetCatsData(
            countryId=self.country,
            webapiKey=self.webapi_key
        ).catsList.item

        categories = []
        for item in category_list:
            categories.append({'id': item.catId, 'name': item.catName, 'parent': item.catParent})

        return categories

    # search for free only, with time fixed at 24h. User can set phrase and category only.

    def search(self, category, phrase):
        params = [{
            'item': ({'filterId': 'category', 'filterValueId': {'item': category}},
                     {'filterId': 'startingTime', 'filterValueId': {'item': self.starting_time}},
                     {'filterId': 'search', 'filterValueId': {'item': phrase}})
        }]
        search_raw_result = self.client.service.doGetItemsList(
            countryId=self.country,
            webapiKey=self.webapi_key,
            filterOptions=params,
        ).itemsList.item

        search = []

        for item in search_raw_result:
            search.append({'id': item.itemId, 'name': item.itemTitle,
                           'type': item.priceInfo.item[0].priceType, 'price': item.priceInfo.item[0].priceValue})

        return search


def choices():
    choice_prep = Allegro()
    choice = choice_prep.get_categories()
    choice_list = []
    add = "'"
    for item in choice:
        if item['parent'] == 0:
            item_name = add + item['name'] + add
            choice_list.append([item['id'], item_name])
    return choice_list


class FreeSearch(models.Model):
    a = choices()
    mail = models.CharField(verbose_name='mail', max_length=100)
    phrase = models.CharField(verbose_name='phrase', max_length=150)
    category = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='category', max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, choices=a)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data końcowa", blank=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.mail, self.phrase, self.category)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Wyszukanie"
        verbose_name = "Wyszukania"
```

Choices should be list of lists where are only two values, id which is decimal max 5 digits and name which contains category names in Allegro auction service.

After calling python manage.py makemigrations in cmd following problem occurs:

```
    C:\Users\Dom\allewatcher>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrat
ions.py", line 63, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47,
in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 176,
 in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 102,
 in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 658, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dom\allewatcher\search\migrations\0001_initial.py", line 20
    ('category', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=6, verbose_nam
e='category', choices=[[26013, Antyki i Sztuka], [98553, Bilety], [64477, Biuro
i Reklama], [19732, Biżuteria i Zegarki], [73973, Delikatesy], [11763, Dla Dziec
i], [5, Dom i Ogród], [63757, Erotyka], [20585, Filmy], [8845, Fotografia], [9,
Gry], [122640, Instrumenty], [6, Kolekcje], [2, Komputery], [122233, Konsole i a
utomaty], [7, Książki i Komiksy], [3, Motoryzacja], [1, Muzyka], [20782, Nieruch
omości], [1454, Odzież, Obuwie, Dodatki], [16696, Przemysł], [76593, Rękodzieło]
, [10, RTV i AGD], [3919, Sport i Turystyka], [122332, Sprzęt estradowy, studyjn
y i DJ-ski], [4, Telefony i Akcesoria], [1429, Uroda], [55067, Wakacje], [121882
, Zdrowie]])),

                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also don't know why in error description there's no quotation marks added by add variable in choices function.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

from **future** import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='FreeSearch',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('mail', models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='mail')),
            ('phrase', models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='phrase')),
            ('category', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=6, verbose_name='category', choices=[[26013, Antyki i Sztuka], [98553, Bilety], [64477, Biuro i Reklama], [19732, Biżuteria i Zegarki], [73973, Delikatesy], [11763, Dla Dzieci], [5, Dom i Ogród], [63757, Erotyka], [20585, Filmy], [8845, Fotografia], [9, Gry], [122640, Instrumenty], [6, Kolekcje], [2, Komputery], [122233, Konsole i automaty], [7, Książki i Komiksy], [3, Motoryzacja], [1, Muzyka], [20782, Nieruchomości], [1454, Odzież, Obuwie, Dodatki], [16696, Przemysł], [76593, Rękodzieło], [10, RTV i AGD], [3919, Sport i Turystyka], [122332, Sprzęt estradowy, studyjny i DJ-ski], [4, Telefony i Akcesoria], [1429, Uroda], [55067, Wakacje], [121882, Zdrowie]])),
            ('end_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, verbose_name='Data końcowa')),
            ('activation_key', models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)),
            ('key_expires', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name': 'Wyszukania',
        },
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be in this item:

```
    Odzież, Obuwie, Dodatki
```

You have a '**,**' sign there which causes syntax error - this value is put directly into `0001_initial.py` file and then makes impression that list item has 4 items instead of two.

To fix it just remove comma from it's value or just escape it somehow (for example by using HTML entity `&#44;` - but it depends on how you are using it further)

---

**EDIT**

Although commas cause problem directly it seems that issue lays deeper. You migration's code's strings were generated without aphostrophes what causes the problem.

I have checked your code - I have created app, copied your code and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations stack
```

*stack is name of my application BTW*

String have been generated with aphostrophes

```
    ('category', models.DecimalField(choices=[[26013, "'Antyki i Sztuka'"], [98553, "'Bilety'"], [64477, "'Biuro i Reklama'"], [19732, "'Bi\u017cuteria i Zegarki'"], [73973, "'Delikatesy'"], [11763, "'Dla Dzieci'"], [5, "'Dom i Ogr\xf3d'"], [63757, "'Erotyka'"], [20585, "'Filmy'"], [8845, "'Fotografia'"], [9, "'Gry'"], [122640, "'Instrumenty'"], [6, "'Kolekcje'"], [2, "'Komputery'"], [122233, "'Konsole i automaty'"], [7, "'Ksi\u0105\u017cki i Komiksy'"], [3, "'Motoryzacja'"], [1, "'Muzyka'"], [20782, "'Nieruchomo\u015bci'"], [1454, "'Odzie\u017c, Obuwie, Dodatki'"], [16696, "'Przemys\u0142'"], [76593, "'R\u0119kodzie\u0142o'"], [10, "'RTV i AGD'"], [3919, "'Sport i Turystyka'"], [122332, "'Sprz\u0119t estradowy, studyjny i DJ-ski'"], [4, "'Telefony i Akcesoria'"], [1429, "'Uroda'"], [55067, "'Wakacje'"], [121882, "'Zdrowie'"]], decimal_places=0, max_digits=6, verbose_name=b'category')),
```

If it is possible I recommend you to delete all files in **your_application/migrations** (avoiding delete `__init__.py`!) and then try to recreate migration by using standard `makemigrations` command.

I have been using Django in 1.9.2 version, suds 0.4 and Python 2.7

Comment: I've changed code in models to replace commas with dashes before it creates choices, but still interpreter detects commas.

Comment: Got one more idea - could you please attach a code of your migration file `C:\Users\Dom\allewatcher\search\migrations\0001_initial.py`?